# Lower-bounding expressions in Maple

Tags: maple

I have the following complicated expression $E(n)$ and I am interested in finding a simple expression $S(n)$ such that $S(n) \leq E(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Does anyone know how one can do this in maple?

$E(n) = $
$$
1/8\,\Biggl( 2\,\sqrt {2\,{n}^{2}-2\,n+1}\sqrt {2}n+\sqrt {2\,{n}^{2}-
2\,n+1}n\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}}-\sqrt {2\,{n}^{2}-2\,n+1}
$$
$$
-\Biggl(18\,{n}^{4}-18\,{n}^{3}+13\,{n}^{2}+8\,\sqrt {2}{n}^{4}\sqrt {
{\frac {{n}^{2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}}-8\,\sqrt {2}{n}^{3}\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2
}+1}{{n}^{2}}}}+4\,\sqrt {2}{n}^{2}\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}
}-8\,\sqrt {2}{n}^{3}+
$$
$$8\,\sqrt {2}{n}^{2}-4\,\sqrt {2}n-4\,n+2-4\,{n}^
{3}\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}}+
$$
$$
4\,{n}^{2}\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{
2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}}-2\,n\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}}+16\,\sqrt {2
\,{n}^{2}-2\,n+1}-16\,\sqrt {2\,{n}^{2}-2\,n+1}n\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2}
+1}{{n}^{2}}}}\Biggr)^{-1/2}\Biggr)
$$
$$ 
{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,{n}^{2}-2\,n+1}}} \left( 
-1+n\sqrt {{\frac {{n}^{2}+1}{{n}^{2}}}} \right) ^{-1}
$$

Comment: sorry I don't know how to add a line break to the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> asympt(E(n),n);

should give you an asymptotic expression for this as $n \to \infty$.  (I would do this myself but I don''t feel like typing this monster into Maple myself, and Maple doesn't read LaTex very well).  If e.g. you get something like $a n^p + b n^{p-1} + O(n^{p-2})$, then
 you might try $S(n) = a n^p + c n^{p-1}$ where $c < b$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do it in Mapple, but I am sure that you can do it "by hand" using some simple inequalities, like
$$
\sqrt{2}\,(n-1)\le\sqrt{2\,n^2-2\,n+1}=\sqrt{n^2+(n-1)^2}\le\sqrt{2}\,n
$$
and
$$
1\le\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}}=\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}\le1+\frac1{2\,n^2}\ .
$$
I am unable to read the rest of the expression, so I cannot give more inequalities.